# Excluding Read only databases using Ola Hallengren script

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren

Is there a way to exclude Standby or Read only databases from Index maintenance and also from backups using Ola Hallengren scripts.

Answer (score 5):

It's available [for backups](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html).

[image: NUTS]

Though it's a somewhat recent addition, so you may need to upgrade your scripts.

For index maintenance, database status is checked so commands don't actually run on databases that aren't fully accessible.

```
IF DATABASEPROPERTYEX(@CurrentDatabaseName,'Status') = 'ONLINE'
AND (@CurrentIsDatabaseAccessible = 1 OR @CurrentIsDatabaseAccessible IS NULL)
AND DATABASEPROPERTYEX(@CurrentDatabaseName,'Updateability') = 'READ_WRITE'
BEGIN
```

Hope this helps!